# How to Put Control Arrows in a website?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

[Arrows](https://pixabay.com/en/arrows-green-left-right-up-down-304834/)

I need to put this in a website. I have buttons with arrow icons, but I want to align them like they are in this picture. Could someone show me how to? and how would the code look like?

Edit: Code provided by the OP in comment section

```html
<form method="post"> <button name="Forward"><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf062;</i></button></div>
  <form method="post"> <button name="Backward"><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf060;</i></button></div>
    <form method="post"> <button name="Left"><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf063;</i></button></div>
      <form method="post"> <button name="Right"><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf061;</i></button></div>
        <form method="post"> <button name="Stop">Stop</button></div>
```

Comment: have you tried something...?...if yes, please share the code

Comment: This code puts arrows in buttons, and I can't place these buttons the way I want.

Comment: your provided code is invalid..

Comment: Yeah that is most likely true, I'm a beginner at best. I just know how to insert the buttons, and that works, I don't know how to change their location on a website.

Answer (score -1):

```css
#up{
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#down{
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#left{
  width: 10px;
}

#right{
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="up"/><br>
<input type="submit" id="left"/>
<input type="submit" id="right"/><br>
<input type="submit" id="down"/>
```

Something like this maybe? 
You can put your arrows inside those buttons.
Just use simple CSS to arrange the buttons